# Send mail reliably with PHP?

Tags: php, smtp

When I use the PHP mail() function my host (A2) sometimes blocks it. When I reached out to them they informed me that sending mail thought SMTP would be a better option. Is this accurate? What is the most reliable way of sending mail via PHP? Can someone give me an example of how to send mail reliably with PHP?

Comment: use PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, PHPMailer is the way to go - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

You need to get access to a SMTP server you will use to send your mail. This could either be the Google SMTP server (a @gmail.com email address) or your company's email server.

A quick example to do this using Google SMTP server is:

1) Install PHPMailer using composer from a terminal / shell:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

2) Include the composer generated autoload file and PHPMailer in your php script:

```
// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

3) Send email using:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'YOUREMAIL@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'YOUREMAILPASSWORD';                               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('YOUREMAIL@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('TOADDRESS');     // Add a recipient

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

$mail->send();
```

Read the PHPMailer documentation at: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Generally sending emails through your hosting SMTP server is more effective than sending emails directly from an application server. As long as the SMTP server has not been black listed, this is accurate.

There are a few good PHP Mail packages. I used SwiftMailer in my projects:
https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/

Quick Example for a basic scenario:
https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html

You can install it using PHP composer (https://getcomposer.org/)